# Separating DisplayMode.PrintLayout from actual printing inside RDLC

Tags: c#, reporting-services, printing, rdlc

I'm maintaining an application that does user-initiated reporting, using the `WinForms.ReportViewer` control. To give people a preview of pagination, we set the report viewer’s display mode to `DisplayMode.PrintLayout`.

However, our report format puts “`Page 1 of 100`” in the header, which means the entire report has to render before displaying the “`Globals!TotalPages`” on the first page, which is raising performance issues for many users.

It would be really great if I could hide “`of 100`” when the report is in the report viewer so the initial page wouldn’t have to wait on “`Globals!TotalPages`”, but print it when the report was being printed, since “`of 100`” is meant to be a quick indicator to consumers of the actual printed report that the report is there in its entirety.

The problem is that none of the obvious discriminators are coming up any different. For both the preview in `ReportViewer` and the actual printed report:

```
Globals!RenderFormat.Name -> "IMAGE"
Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive -> false
Globals!RenderFormat.DeviceInfo("OutputFormat") -> "emf"
```

Is there a way to tell from within the report itself that the report is being shown in `ReportViewer` and not printed to a printer, or does using `DisplayMode.PrintLayout` remove all ability to make that distinction?

There is no separate `.Render` call made to render the `ReportViewer`; it’s embedded in some XAML as

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="WindowsFormsHost" Grid.Row="1">
  <winForms:ReportViewer x:Name="ReportViewer" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowToolBar="False"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

and I imagine the call to `window.Show()` chains through to `.Render`.

However, I do have backing code with full access to monitor `ReportViewer` events. Maybe I can inject something into `DeviceInfo` in one place or another?

Comment: Have you tried setting the PageCountMode (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.pagecountmode.aspx) to Estimate? I doubt it'll make a difference as it should be set to Estimate by default but the documentation says that "it'll change it depending on the report" so it's possible it's overridden. This makes sense for getting a page total though. Perhaps your report type or format is forcing it to actual on first render causing it to calculate the actual number of pages and leading to the performance hit?

Comment: Yes. The viewer's DisplayMode is set to DisplayMode.PrintLayout. Globals!TotalPages is a directive inside the report, not calling the GetTotalPages method on the ReportViewer. (And even if it were, that only uses Actual in DisplayMode.PrintLayout, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489264.aspx.)

Comment: Okay. So there's no way of controlling the evaluation of directives (built-in variables) via the ReportViewer control. Unfortunately I don't believe we can tell from within the report if it's being shown in Report Viewer or printed because the render format "IMAGE" includes TIFF and Print. Can you show your Render method call if you're using it?

Comment: Updated the original question with information on how Report Viewer is implicitly called. I can listen to all relevant events on the viewer, if that helps.